# Unit Testing in Android Studio - How?

Tags: unit-testing, android-studio, android-testing

I want to run unit tests in Android studio. This isn't something I've done before. What I can see is that under src, along side main(where my application code exists) there is also another directory entitled androidTest/java/myPackageName and then a file called ApplicationTest

This file contains:

```
package com.mypackage.myapplicationname;

import android.app.Application;
import android.test.ApplicationTestCase;

/**
 * <a href="http://d.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html">Testing Fundamentals</a>
 */
public class ApplicationTest extends ApplicationTestCase<Application> {
    public ApplicationTest() {
        super(Application.class);

    }
}
```

From all the examples that I've found, I can't see anyone telling me to use this and just add my test cases to it. I'm seeing examples telling me to create a new directory, add it to 'defaultConfig' as testPackageName etc... but no example says, use this as it's already set up.

I'm thus very, very confused.

If anyone can point me in the right direction please, I'd very much appreciate it.

I have looked at https://developer.android.com/studio/test/index.html however again it doesn't discuss this setup at all.

Any help would be gratefully accepted please.

Answer (score 0):

[Best Practices for Testing](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/start/index.html#test-types) is a great place to start with testing in Android. In brief, when new project is created, Android Studio creates also two folders where you can put your tests:

> - `/src/test/java/` for tests that run on the local JVM and do not have access to functional Android framework APIs (e.g. Unit Tests)
> - `/src/androidTest/java/` for all tests that must run on an Android hardware device or an Android emulator